# Show common characters in two string without duplicates

Tags: java, character

I need to write a program that should ask two strings from user and show the common characters in this.

It must not have duplicates: even if ‘a’ is found more than once in both strings, it should be displayed only once.

My Java knowledge is very limited, so I'm not looking for efficiency but for understandability.

---

Here is what I came up with at the moment.

```
//Get String 1
System.out.print( "Enter a string: " );
string1 = sc.next();

//Get String 2
System.out.print( "Enter another string: " );
string2 = sc.next();

System.out.print ( "Common characters: " );
//Common chars           
for ( a = 0 ; a < string1.length() ; a++){
    for ( b = 0 ; b < string2.length() ; b++){
        if ( string1.charAt(a) == string2.charAt(b) ){
            System.out.print(string1.charAt(a));
        }
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: If you seek for help about your code quality and not his functionning (considering your lack of actual question, I guess it is the case), I recommend you posting your question on [the Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Maybe the question on counting letter repetition in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188316/count-the-letter-repetition-in-a-string/188320#188320) gives you some ideas how you might deal with.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `chars()` stream of the input string, e.g.:

```
public class StringCharCount {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String s1 = args[0];
    final String s2 = args[1];

    s1.chars()
        .distinct()
        .mapToObj(ch -> String.valueOf((char) ch))
        .filter(s2::contains)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

This works with Java 8 or later.

- `chars()` creates a stream of characters from the string
- `distinct()` ensures, that each value occurs only once
- `mapToObj(...)` is required, because the `String#contains()` method requires a `String` as input. So we are converting the stream value to a `String`. Unfortunately, Java has issues with the primitive types, so the stream of `chars` is in fact a stream of `int`. So we have to cast each value to `char`.
- `forEach(...)` prints each value to `System.out`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `Set<Character>`. This would naturally handle the duplicate issue and has a simple `retainAll` method to do the heavy lifting for you.

```
private Set<Character> characterSet(String s) {
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
    // Put each character in the string into the set.
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        set.add(s.charAt(i));
    }
    return set;
}


public Set<Character> common(String a, String b) {
    // Make a set out of each string.
    Set<Character> aSet = characterSet(a);
    Set<Character> bSet = characterSet(b);
    // Work out the common characters using retainAll.
    Set<Character> common = new HashSet<>(aSet);
    common.retainAll(bSet);
    return common;
}

public void test(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(common("abcdef", "afxyzfffaa"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set`

```
        String str1 = "abcdefg";
        String str2 = "abcaaadefg";

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        Set<Character> sets = new HashSet<Character>();
        for(char ch : str1.toCharArray()){//init
            sets.add(ch);
        }
        for(char ch : str2.toCharArray()){
            if(sets.contains(ch)){//str1 char contains str2 char
                result.append(ch);
                sets.remove(ch);//avoid duplicates
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result.toString());
```